# TFS: is it possible to mark work items with groups?

Tags: tfs

What I want to do is to have ability to link any work item to few projects. Let's imaging I have "ProductA" and "ProductB" projects that communicate to each other. There is issue linked to communication error between few components of both projects... I would like to have some kind of repository like "Projects" and add to my issue labels "ProjectA" and "ProjectB".

It is something similar to what gmail provides.

Is it possible to do that in TFS?

Thanks a lot, any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

A couple ideas:

You could potentially do a multi-select list of projects, but that would entail creating a new client-side control to display them, and making changes to the WorkItem template.

Another thing you could do is create issues for each of the projects, then link them (as child workitems if you have TFS 2010) to a master issue.

A "quick-and-dirty" way of doing it would be to use a text field within your WorkItem, and simply use convention in that field (e.g. Team Project names separated by a semicolon "Project A; Project B"

Of the three, I'd suggest creating the linked issues. Ultimately that's the one that's going to support reporting the best.

Answer (score 1):

If productA and productB are across different team projects. In my experience, you can add one work item then you can create another one in another team project. The way to connect each other is using Links.

If ProductA and ProductB are inside a single team project, I think the solution will be easier. You can create one parent work item (like Product Backlog Item or PBI in Scrum) then create two children work items from it which will be (like Tasks or Sprint Backlog Item) then assgin to two teams. You can edit the template by adding teams.

Hope this helps.